# Remove trailing keywords after localhost

Tags: .net, url, iis, dns, hosting

I have a site which is hosted in my local system in IIS which having URL pattern like this

https://localhost/something

I need this same website need to be loaded when i hit the url

https://localhost

what is the IIS setting i need to do for this?

Please note this website is a web application not a website project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URL Rewrite component. It can be installed from Web Platform Installer.

This is simple setting:

```
<rule name="target redirect" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^target$" />
 <action type"redirect" url="/newlocation" />
</rule>
```